# Adding two timestamps in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two fields in sql `date1 varchar(4)` and `date2 varchar(4)`. The date format is just `HHmm` where HH is the hours and mm is the minutes.

Is there anyway in SQL which we can add the two timestamps together and work out how many hours and minutes?

e.g.

```
date1 = 0230  date2 = 0145 will total 0415
date1 = 0030  date2 = 0035 will total 0105
```

Comment: FYI, it's not a bad idea to specify the DBMS in question's tags.

Comment: sorry didnt see that you could add extra tags in the Edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @d1 varchar(4), @d2 varchar(4), @dif int

set @d1 = '0230'
set @d2 = '0145'

set @dif = (CAST(left(@d1, 2) as int) * 60) + (CAST(left(@d2, 2) as int) * 60) + CAST(right(@d1, 2) as int) + CAST(right(@d2, 2) as int)

select RIGHT('00' + cast(floor(@dif / 60) as varchar), 2) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@dif % 60 as varchar),2)
```

Comment: thanks this is just what I wanted. was going to go the substring route but left and right is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure these are really timestamps, what not store them as integers?

Anyhow.. not sure there is a mysql function for this.
You can browse: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
Not sure it will offer much help.
If you store them as seconds, then you can simply have mysql add them, otherwise pull them into a script, convert them to seconds, add them together and then convert to a more readable format if desired.

Comment: Brad its a legacy thing hence I just need to be able to do the manipulations. Im thinking I may just need to use substring and split up the hours and minutes then work something out

Answer (score 0):

Try this (use time or date time):

```
 select ADDTIME(time1,time2);
```

In mysql time is of the form

```
'01:02:03'
```

and date time is

```
 '2003-12-31 01:02:03'
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you happen to be using SQL Server you may also be able to use the DATEDIFF function described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

This will let you get the difference between any part of a datetime value. DATEADD may be of use for this as well depending on how you want to handle it.

Comment: OP has `varchar` values. Not `datetime`